# Passing structs to threads in rust

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have a function that takes in a reference to a relatively big struct. The function spawns a few threads using tokio that will take in the struct. None of the threads need to modify the struct.

This is a contrived example:

```rust
   #[tokio::main]
    async fn search(&self, struct_a: Arc<StructA>) {
        for i in 0..10 {
            task::spawn(async move {
                // do something with struct_a
            });
        }
    }
```

If I just pass the references to the thread rust will complain that I am trying to move a borrowed value, which makes sense. So this is what i think my options are:

1. Clone the actual struct and pass it to the thread. This is expensive.
2. Have the function take in a `Arc<StructA>`, and then calling `arcOfA.clone()` and pass that to the thread. This will avoid cloning the actual struct and should solve the borrowed value issue

Any other option? Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: Yes, That is correct @Nicola

Comment: Arc can be used if you only need the reference of that struct
if you need mutable access you can further wrap the struct to a `Mutex` and then `Arc`

Answer (score 1):

Your two ideas are correct (though the expense of cloning the struct should not be overestimated, it depends what's in the structure and how large it is).

But depending what you do in the individual tasks you might also be able to create simple futures and [`join!()`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/macro.join.html) them together as a single one (more likely via something like [`FuturesOrdered`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/prelude/stream/struct.FuturesOrdered.html) or [`join_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/fn.join_all.html) though). If the work is primarily threading IO and there's relatively little CPU work it should be fine.

If you'd been using regular threads I'd have suggested [scoped threads](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scope.html), but you're not. There's [an async-scoped](https://crates.io/crates/async-scoped) but apparently it's pretty limiting as it essentially busy waits [for soundness reasons](https://wishawa.github.io/posts/thread-scoped-async/).

Comment: [Just recently a very good blog post about scoped async tasks was published](https://tmandry.gitlab.io/blog/posts/2023-03-01-scoped-tasks/).

Comment: could you give an example of what "But depending what you do in the individual tasks you might also be able to create simple futures and join!() them together as a single one" would look like for my use case?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d3fd2638477558e643368d7197423ece